# Is every GO-space collectionwise normal?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

Is every GO-space collectionwise normal? And what is the relation between collectionwise normal and monotonically normal? I know a GO-space is always monotonically normal. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, monotonically normal spaces are collectionwise normal.
  (And this answers your first question.)

> Suppose that $\mathcal{H}$ is a discrete family of closed subsets of $X$.  Note that for $H \in \mathcal{H}$ the set $\hat{H} = \bigcup \{ K \in \mathcal{H} : K \neq H \}$ is a closed set disjoint from $H$, and so consider $U_H = D_X ( H , \hat{H} )$.  (Where $D_X$ denotes the *monotone normality operator* on $X$.)
>
> Given distinct $H , H^\prime \in \mathcal{H}$ by the monotonicity of $D_X$ it follows that $U_H \cap U_{H^\prime} = D_X ( H , \hat{H} ) \cap D_X ( H^\prime , \hat{H}^\prime ) \subseteq D ( H , H^\prime ) \cap D ( H^\prime , H ) = \emptyset$, and so the family $\{ U_H : H \in \mathcal{H} \}$ is pairwise disjoint.

---

Information about monotonically normal spaces can be found in

> R. W. Heath, D. J. Lutzer and P. L. Zenor, *Monotonically normal spaces*,  Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 178 (1973), 481-493, [MR0372826](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=372826); [link](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1973-178-00/S0002-9947-1973-0372826-2/)

The above is essentially a re-working of Theorem 3.1 of this paper.